# Map Reduce or Aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I have such kind of database in mongoddb, now my question is how to get aggregate result from database.

```
_id  time    pow
 1    t1     20
 2    t2     20
 3    t3     20
 4    t4     30
 5    t5     30
 6    t6     20
 7    t6     20
```

I want result in following format.

```
{ _id:1,  time:t1,  pow:20}
{ _id:4,  time:t4,  pow:30}
{ _id:6, time:t6,   pow:20}
```

Any one has idea about how to get such kind of result?

Comment: What kind of uniqueness are you looking for. What query are you "firing". If you "fire" your query and get a result, why are you asking how to get this result? (just use your query)

Comment: I want query that give me above result.

Comment: What's the logic behind your result - why are t2 and t3 and t5 omitted for example?

Comment: i need result for power at particular time, so  i check power for next time if its repeat ? then omit that document,this procedure until power value is not changed.

Comment: have you tried anything or you just outsource your work to a cheap labor?

Comment: Have you any idea about my question what should i have to do.? Actually i have do that thing using code but in that case it retrive all the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually from the question and the comments you have provided, we do not require to use aggregation here. You just have to use a loop the whole list, indexed by id, and capture the change in 'pow'. That's all.